# Azure Devops - Can not change the category of inherited work item state

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I inherited a process from the Agile Process on Azure Devops and I'm trying out a few things. I moved the **Resolved** state for User Story from the Resolved category to In Progress (see attached image).

[image]

Now I want to return it back to the Resolved category but I can't find a way to do it. I've played around many options all to no avail.

The process customization documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=azure-devops) doesn't provide information about this.
Is it impossible to move it back once I've changed the category? I think I've done something like this in the past but I can't remember exactly how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

No, that was defined by default. Here is the default Agile process template:

[image]

We can not change inherited states. We can just hide/unhide them. You can find help string on the States page:

> For each work item type, you can customize the workflow to support
>   your team's process. From this page you can add and remove custom
>   states as well as hide inherited states

Comment: You're right, the Resolved state comes under the "In Progress" category by default.
I thought it would make more sense to move it to the "Resolved" category. Thanks anyway